# Xdebug, just won't run ( waiting for connection), PHP 8, NetBeans 14, Mac OSX Monterey, MAMP Pro 6

Tags: php, xdebug, mamp-pro

I've been reading posts on here and trying various things on my set up all day and drawing a blank. I have a MacBook Pro, running Monterey 12.5.1 with NetBeans 14, MAMP PRO 6 and Xdebug 3 all installed.

When I try to debug my code I just get a message saying 'waiting for connection to netbeans-x-debug' and then after a while I stop it manually and I get a message saying no connection to Xdebug was detected.

In `phpinfo()` I can see that Xdebug extension is loaded, so I know it's there, NetBeans and Xdebug just don't appear to be talking to each other.

The native Mac OS firewall is off, and I've set my project port to `9000`, NetBeans to `9000` and php.ini to `9000`.

php.ini for Xdebug is as follows:

```ini
[xdebug]
MAMP_Xdebug_MAMPzend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable=On

; Unlike Xdebug 2, where there was an enabling setting for each feature, with 
; Xdebug 3 you put Xdebug into a specific mode, which can be configured with the
; xdebug.mode setting.
;
; This setting, in combination with xdebug.start_with_request is the new way to
; enable functionality, and to configure when Xdebug's feature activates.

; Please also note: Xdebug's default debugging port has changed from 9000 to 9003.
; For compatability reason within the MAMP environment the port is still set to 9000.
xdebug.client_port=9000

; Use a Unix domain socket (only a select few debugging clients) instead of
; hostname or IP address of IDE or debugging client is listening for incoming
; debugging connections.
;xdebug.client_host=unix:///path/to/sock
;xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_host=localhost

; Enable Profiling, with which you can analyse performance bottlenecks.
; Replaces xdebug.profiler_enable
xdebug.mode=profile

; The directory where Xdebug will write tracing, profiling, and garbage collection 
; statistics to. This directory needs to be writable for the system user with which
; PHP is running. Replaces xdebug.profiler_output_dir
xdebug.output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp"
```

In the NetBeans project run configuration, in "Advanced" I have left debugger proxy as `localhost` and the port is `9000`.

And in NetBeans prefs, under "PHP > Debugging", the port is set to `9000`.

My project runs perfectly on the Mac at `https://wip.rich.local:8890`

Perhaps I am not passing the right `client_host` address but I have tried `wip.rich.local` and still the same problem.

There are a lot of posts on StackOverflow about this but they are all quite old, and the fixes suggested have not helped... Does anyone have an up to date install running?

Comment: you have two mode settings in file , start with `debug`.  Also add a line for xdebug logging , on my box : xdebug.log = "/usr/local/mnt/media/log/xdebug.log".  Make certain the directory is writable by the user running web server !   Restart php-fpm if you use that. Restart apache (or whatever mamp is.  Try debugging again. tail the log file. Let it tell you what is going on.

Comment: Check your live settings with what `xdebug_info()` reports. As YvesLeBorg stated, your `xdebug.mode` is NOT `debug` -- it gets overwritten by `xdebug.mode=profile` later.

Comment: also (old news but still) if you use php-fpm (via mamp dunno if possible) , both fpm and xdebug came out-of-the-box on port 9000.  Make certain your client can grab the port, or better yet switch xdebug to another port alltogether.